# All jmeter requests going to only one server with haproxy

Tags: load-balancing, jmeter, haproxy

I'm using Jmeter to load test my web application. I have two web servers and we are using HAProxy for load balance. All my tests are running fine and configured correctly. I have three jmeter remote clients so I can run my tests distributed. The problem I'm facing is that ALL my jmeter requests are only being processed by one of the web servers. For some reason it's not balancing and I'm having many time outs, and huge response times. I've looked around a lot for a way to make these requests being balanced, but I'm having no luck so far. Does anyone know what can be the cause of this behavior? Please let me know if you need to know anything about my environment first and I will provide the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your haproxy configuration:

- What is it's load balancing policy, if not round-robin is it based on ip source or some other info that might be common to your 3 remote servers?
- Are you sure load balancing is working right? Try testing with browser first, if you can add some information about the web server in response to debug.

Check your test plan:

- Are you sure you don't have somewhere in your requests a sessionid that is hardcoded?
- How many threads did you configure?

Comment: I'm in a office network environment. My IP according to the proxy server is the external ip of the office (so, same IP for my 3 remote servers). The load balancing is working right from the browser, though. And the test plan does not have any cookies hardcoded. I wonder if there's any jmeter config I have to do? With round robin balance I get the same results.

Comment: When you test with browser are you testing from the same machines that serve as remote servers ? What's the policy of your haproxy ipbased or roundrobin ? How do you check that test with browser is fine ? You open 3 browsers and each one goes to a different server ?

Comment: Yes. It's working now with round robin. The network admin had it setup wrongly, so I mentioned before I had tried with round robin, but I hadn't really. Now I have and it's working. Thanks very much for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

In your Jmeter script by default the HTTP Request "Use KeepAlive" header option is checked.

> Keep-Alive is a header that maintains a persistent connection between
>   client and server, preventing a connection from breaking
>   intermittently. Also known as HTTP keep-alive, it can be defined as a
>   method to allow the same TCP connection for HTTP communication instead
>   of opening a new connection for each new request.

This may cause all requests to go to the same server. Just uncheck the option and save, stop your script and re-run.